# How do I make Microsoft Word citations hyperlinks?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, citations

So for cross references (to tables, figures, etc) Word will make the reference link to the spot in the document that contains the caption like you expect but it seems for citations it doesn't do this. You can't ctrl+click them to go to their location which is odd. Is there anyway to change their behavior that clicking on them links to their position in the generated References page?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is "no."

It is precisely *because* the Reference page is automatically generated that this functionality is not available. (For the same reason that outline headers don't hyperlink *back* to the generated Table of Contents.) (Conceivably, I suppose, citations on the reference page *could* link back to where they are cited in the document, but of course this would be problematic due to the 1-*n* nature of citations.)

What is it that you are trying to accomplish? You realize, I'm sure, that you can edit the citations right on the page, right?

Comment: I don't agree with the "precisely because" part of this answer. There is no technical limitation blocking the automatic link creation from a place of a citation to the bibliography list entry. There are other typesetting tools supporting this. Also, the comparison with headlines is a bit misleading - jumping from a headline to "its entry" in the ToC would not bring much - there is no additional information. On the other hand, jumping from a citation to the bibliography for additional information (source title, author, identification...) is a usual need when reading any text with citations.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it does not look like this is possible.  There do appear to be add-ins, such as [Endnote](https://endnote.com/), that enable you to do this, as seen [here](https://libguides.utoledo.edu/c.php?g=284330&p=1895343).